# WPF windows is hidden when call win32

Tags: c#, wpf, delphi, winapi

I have a win32 application (written in Delphi), that calls some WPF windows.
These WPF windows calls other windows in win32 Delphi projects (to reuse some code). When I do this, it hides (send to background) the WPF windows.

These win32 windows are in COM dlls.

There is a way to avoid this behavior?

I need something like this:

```
+--------------------------------------------------
|  win32
|
|
|
|  +-------------------------------------+
|  |  wpf                                |
|  |                                     |
|  |                                     |
|  |                                     |
|  |  +--------------------+             |
|  |  |  win32             |             |
|  +--|                    |-------------+
|     |                    |             
|     +--------------------+             
|                                       
|
```

but I get:

```
+--------------------------------------------------
|  win32
|
|
|
|  
|  
|  
|  
|  
|     +--------------------+             
|     |  win32             |             
|     |                    |             
|     |                    |             
|     +--------------------+             
|                                       
|
```

In delphi main project I have used "CreateOleObject" to get access to wpf code.
In WPF, the windows is opened using "ShowDialog()" command.
Again, in WPF I call delphi, using interop references to my win32 dlls.

Ok, the code used is bellow:

Delphi main application:

```
var dll : OleVariant;
begin
  dll := CreateOleObject("MyDllinCSharp.ClassName");
  dll.DoSomething(...);
```

at this point, wpf windows comes to front:

wpf code:

```
var form = new MyForm();
form.ShowDialog();
```

In xaml, nothing important, only a basic window:

```
<Window x:Class="MyForm"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Reverter" Height="432" Width="500" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
```

now in c#, I will call a delphi DLL, after I reference the COM dll in c# project:

```
var dll = Delphi.CreateInstance("delphidll", "Interfacename") as IMyProcess;

dll.DoSomethingInDelphi(....);
```

Comment: Without more detail it is hard to help

Comment: Are you able to replicate the behaviour with a very simple Delphi -> WPF -> Delphi code snippet ?

Comment: Ok, I have been updated.

Comment: Code is surely important. Please add an SSCCE.

Comment: What do you mean that you cannot provide code. Imagine if you told the compiler that you could not provide code. Clearly you can provide code. It looks to me as though you are not trying hard enough.

Comment: Hi David, I tried to copy some code. This is the way we do here. Thanks.

Comment: @paulo, try to create code that reproduces the problem and/or the scenario to enable us to help you.

Answer (score 2):

I got this to work, hosting the Win32 window inside WPF element, like this walkthrough:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752055.aspx

Now I havesomething like this:

```
+--------------------------------------------------
|  win32
|
|
|
|  +-------------------------------------+
|  |  wpf                                |
|  |                                     |
|  |                                     |
|  |  -wpf------------------             |
|  | |+--------------------+|            |
|  | ||  win32             ||            |
|  +-||                    ||------------+
|    ||                    ||             
|    |+--------------------+|             
|     ----------------------                                   
|
```